# Alternate vertical scroll and horizontal scroll with normal scroll movement

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I have to create a page with a part on horizontal scroll.
So I have a normal first section, the second is bigger than 100vw (depends on how many item in) and when you scroll down, it scroll in to the right. When the second is to the right end, it scroll down and you arrive to the third section.

I know I'm explaining poorly so here is an example in real site :
https://beauvoir.ca/?fbclid=IwAR2n6xT-RPXpK3_xraDrkh6rxUqhL4eoay6cwo5Z67c-kRECHizfZpYeRP0

And here is what i've done :

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {

        let divWidth = $('.section__two__list').width();
        let divHeight = $('.section__two').height();
        let screenWidth = $('.section__two__container').width();
        let fullDistance = divWidth - screenWidth;
        let newDivHeight = divHeight + fullDistance;
        $('.section__two').css('height',  newDivHeight);

        $(window).scroll(function (e) {
                let startPoint = window.pageYOffset - 
 $('.section__two').offset().top;
                let endPoint = window.pageYOffset - ($('.section__two').offset().top + fullDistance);

                 if (startPoint >= 0 && endPoint <= 0) {
                        $('.section__two__container').css('transform', 'translate(-' + startPoint + 'px, 0px)');
                        $('.section__two__list').css('transform', 'translate(0px, ' + startPoint + 'px)');
                 }
         });
});
```

```css
body,
html{
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section__one{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: chocolate;
}

.section__two{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.section__two__container{
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 10vh 0;
}

.section__two__list{
    /* Reset */
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    /* Css */
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.section__two__item{
    width: 600px;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.section__three{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="section__one">

    </div>

    <div class="section__two">
        <div class="section__two__container">
            <ul class="section__two__list">
                <li class="section__two__item"></li>
                <li class="section__two__item"></li>
                <li class="section__two__item"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section__three">

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that i didn't achieved to do something that don't drop up and down when the scroll is horizontal. I'm wondering if i can add some code to lift the animation or maybe my all code isn't the right to do what i want.

Thanks in advance for the time that you will take to help me !

Comment: If you're not opposed to using a library to achieve what I believe you're describing you could use something like Greensock's ScrollTrigger [Codepen: Horizontal section scrolling - ScrollTrigger](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/eYpOZvX)

Comment: If it works, i'm not opposed ^^ That looks like what I'm looking for, I'll test it and i'll tell you if it's fine for my purpose ! Thanks